# Idiomatic Clojure way to find most frequent items in a seq

Tags: clojure, idioms

Given a sequence of items I want to find the n most frequent items, in descending order of frequency.  So for example I would like this unit test to pass:

```
(fact "can find 2 most common items in a sequence"
      (most-frequent-n 2 ["a" "bb" "a" "x" "bb" "ccc" "dddd" "dddd" "bb" "dddd" "bb"]) 
      =>
      '("bb" "dddd"))
```

I am fairly new to Clojure and still trying to get to grip with the standard library.  Here is what I came up with:

```
(defn- sort-by-val [s]        (sort-by val s))
(defn- first-elements [pairs] (map #(get % 0) pairs))

(defn most-frequent-n [n items]
  "return the most common n items, e.g. 
     (most-frequent-n 2 [:a :b :a :d :x :b :c :d :d :b :d :b])  => 
         => (:d :b)"
  (take n (->
           items               ; [:a :b :a :d :x :b :c :d :d :b :d :b]
           frequencies         ; {:a 2, :b 4, :d 4, :x 1, :c 1}
           seq                 ; ([:a 2] [:b 4] [:d 4] [:x 1] [:c 1])
           sort-by-val         ; ([:x 1] [:c 1] [:a 2] [:b 4] [:d 4])
           reverse             ; ([:d 4] [:b 4] [:a 2] [:c 1] [:x 1])
           first-elements)))   ; (:d :b :a :c :x)
```

However this seems like a complicated chain of functions to do a fairly common operation.  Is there a more elegant or more idiomatic (or more efficient) way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you have discovered, typically you would use a combination of sort-by and frequencies to get a frequency-sorted list.

```
(sort-by val (frequencies ["a" "bb" "a" "x" "bb" "ccc" "dddd" "dddd" "bb" "dddd" "bb"]))
=> (["x" 1] ["ccc" 1] ["a" 2] ["dddd" 3] ["bb" 4])
```

Then you can manipulate this fairly easily to get the lowest / highest frequency items. Perhaps something like:

```
(defn most-frequent-n [n items]
  (->> items
    frequencies
    (sort-by val)
    reverse
    (take n)
    (map first)))
```

Which again is pretty similar to your solution (apart from that you don't need the helper functions with clever use of the `->>` macro).

So overall I think your solution is pretty good. Don't worry about the chain of functions - it's actually a very short solution for what is logically quite a complicated concept. Try coding the same thing in C# / Java and you will see what I mean......

Comment: Thanks Mikera, your solution is a nice improvement. (1) I see how to use the arrow macros properly to avoid need of helper functions. (2)  `sort-by` can work directly on the result of `frequencies` without requiring doing a `seq` first. (3) There is a `first` function in the standard library so I don't need to create my own. (4) Doing the `take` before the `map` is probably more efficient.

Comment: `(reverse (sort-by f coll))` is dreadfully expensive for no real reason - prefer instead `(sort-by (comp - f) coll)`. Also, I'd be consistent about whether you use `first` and `second` or `key` and `val`, since they're equivalent for map entries.